# Failure of release upgrade from 14.04 LTS to 16.04 LTS because of ubuntu-desktop package dependencies

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, upgrade, dependencies, qt

Context: I attempted an upgrade from 14.04 LTS to 16.04 LTS, and everything went smoothly until just near the end when I got a message that although the upgrade had been installed, some errors had occurred. Doing a bit of digging, it seemed that the 'ubuntu-desktop' package had some unsolvable dependencies. Output of /var/log/dist-upgrade/apt.log:

```
Log time: 2017-01-09 10:30:59.192116
Starting pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 1
Starting 2 pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 1
Investigating (0) qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-ui-toolkit-plugin [ amd64 ] < none -> 1.3.1918+16.04.20160404-0ubuntu1 > ( libs )
Broken qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-ui-toolkit-plugin:amd64 Depends on qml-module-ubuntu-components [ amd64 ] < none -> 1.3.1918+16.04.20160404-0ubuntu1 > ( libs )
  Considering qml-module-ubuntu-components:amd64 1 as a solution to qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-ui-toolkit-plugin:amd64 0
  Holding Back qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-ui-toolkit-plugin:amd64 rather than change qml-module-ubuntu-components:amd64
Investigating (0) checkbox-converged [ amd64 ] < none -> 1.2.4-0ubuntu1 > ( oldlibs )
Broken checkbox-converged:amd64 Depends on qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-ui-toolkit-plugin [ amd64 ] < none -> 1.3.1918+16.04.20160404-0ubuntu1 > ( libs )
  Considering qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-ui-toolkit-plugin:amd64 0 as a solution to checkbox-converged:amd64 -1
  Holding Back checkbox-converged:amd64 rather than change qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-ui-toolkit-plugin:amd64
Investigating (1) checkbox-gui [ amd64 ] < none -> 1.2.4-0ubuntu1 > ( utils )
Broken checkbox-gui:amd64 Depends on checkbox-converged [ amd64 ] < none -> 1.2.4-0ubuntu1 > ( oldlibs )
  Considering checkbox-converged:amd64 -1 as a solution to checkbox-gui:amd64 0
  Holding Back checkbox-gui:amd64 rather than change checkbox-converged:amd64
Investigating (1) ubuntu-desktop [ amd64 ] < 1.361 > ( metapackages )
Broken ubuntu-desktop:amd64 Depends on checkbox-gui [ amd64 ] < none -> 1.2.4-0ubuntu1 > ( utils )
  Considering checkbox-gui:amd64 0 as a solution to ubuntu-desktop:amd64 0
  Removing ubuntu-desktop:amd64 rather than change checkbox-gui:amd64
Done
Starting pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 1
Starting 2 pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 1
Investigating (0) ubuntu-desktop [ amd64 ] < 1.361 > ( metapackages )
Broken ubuntu-desktop:amd64 Depends on checkbox-gui [ amd64 ] < none -> 1.2.4-0ubuntu1 > ( utils )
  Considering checkbox-gui:amd64 1 as a solution to ubuntu-desktop:amd64 10000
    Reinst Failed early because of qtdeclarative-abi-5-5-0:amd64
    Reinst Failed because of libubuntugestures5:amd64
    Reinst Failed because of qml-module-ubuntu-components:amd64
    Reinst Failed because of qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-ui-toolkit-plugin:amd64
    Reinst Failed because of checkbox-converged:amd64
Done
ERROR:root:failed to mark 'ubuntu-desktop' for install (E:Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.)
```

However, my system seemed to be doing fine on 16.04 so I ignored this for a little while. But recently, my laptop has been a bit buggy (system fonts not displaying upon re-wake and inability to shutdown properly following this), so I think it is best I try to get 'ubuntu-desktop' installed. I made some of my own attempts using synaptic and aptitude from the command line (instead of apt-get) to see if their smart dependency resolving could help, but to no avail. The output of `sudo aptitude install ubuntu-desktop` is very similar to the apt.log above [**edit**: included in full upon request in comments, and I have also included the result upon rejecting the first dependency resolution suggestion]

```
$ sudo aptitude install ubuntu-desktop
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  checkbox-converged{a} checkbox-gui{a} libandroid-properties1{a} libhardware2{a} libhybris{a} libhybris-common1{a} libmedia1{a} liboxideqt-qmlplugin{a} liboxideqtcore0{ab} liboxideqtquick0{a} 
  libqt5organizer5{ab} libqt5quicktest5{a} libubuntugestures5{ab} libubuntutoolkit5{ab} libunity-webapps0{a} pyotherside{a} python3-aptdaemon.pkcompat{ab} qml-module-io-thp-pyotherside{a} 
  qml-module-qt-labs-folderlistmodel{a} qml-module-qt-labs-settings{a} qml-module-qtgraphicaleffects{a} qml-module-qtquick-layouts{a} qml-module-qttest{a} qml-module-ubuntu-components{ab} 
  qml-module-ubuntu-layouts{ab} qml-module-ubuntu-performancemetrics{a} qml-module-ubuntu-test{ab} qml-module-ubuntu-web{a} qmlscene{a} qtdeclarative5-dev-tools{a} qtdeclarative5-test-plugin{a} 
  qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-ui-toolkit-plugin{a} suru-icon-theme{a} ubuntu-desktop ubuntu-mobile-icons{a} unity-webapps-common{a} unity-webapps-qml{a} unity-webapps-service{a} webapp-container{ab} 
  webbrowser-app{ab} 
0 packages upgraded, 40 newly installed, 0 to remove and 63 not upgraded.
Need to get 43.8 MB/44.2 MB of archives. After unpacking 161 MB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 qml-module-ubuntu-test : Depends: qtbase-abi-5-5-1 which is a virtual package, provided by:
                                    - libqt5core5a, but 5.6.1+dfsg-3ubuntu1~xenialoverlay1~4+fix1 is installed.                                    - libqt5core5a, but 5.6.1+dfsg-3ubuntu1~xenialoverlay1~4+fix1 is installed.
 liboxideqtcore0 : Depends: qtbase-abi-5-5-1 which is a virtual package, provided by:
                             - libqt5core5a, but 5.6.1+dfsg-3ubuntu1~xenialoverlay1~4+fix1 is installed.                             - libqt5core5a, but 5.6.1+dfsg-3ubuntu1~xenialoverlay1~4+fix1 is installed.
 libqt5organizer5 : Depends: qtbase-abi-5-5-1 which is a virtual package, provided by:
                              - libqt5core5a, but 5.6.1+dfsg-3ubuntu1~xenialoverlay1~4+fix1 is installed.                              - libqt5core5a, but 5.6.1+dfsg-3ubuntu1~xenialoverlay1~4+fix1 is installed.
 webapp-container : Depends: qtbase-abi-5-5-1 which is a virtual package, provided by:
                              - libqt5core5a, but 5.6.1+dfsg-3ubuntu1~xenialoverlay1~4+fix1 is installed.                              - libqt5core5a, but 5.6.1+dfsg-3ubuntu1~xenialoverlay1~4+fix1 is installed.
                    Depends: qtdeclarative-abi-5-5-0 which is a virtual package, provided by:
                              - libqt5qml5, but 5.6.1-4ubuntu1~xenialoverlay1~4 is installed.
 qml-module-ubuntu-layouts : Depends: qtdeclarative-abi-5-5-0 which is a virtual package, provided by:
                                       - libqt5qml5, but 5.6.1-4ubuntu1~xenialoverlay1~4 is installed.
 python3-aptdaemon.pkcompat : Depends: python3-aptdaemon (= 1.1.1+bzr982-0ubuntu14) but 1.1.1+bzr982-0ubuntu16~ubuntu16.04~ppa1 is installed.
                              Conflicts: packagekit but 1.1.1-1ubuntu1~ubuntu16.04~ppa1 is installed.
                              Conflicts: packagekit:i386 but it is not going to be installed.
 qml-module-ubuntu-components : Depends: qtbase-abi-5-5-1 which is a virtual package, provided by:
                                          - libqt5core5a, but 5.6.1+dfsg-3ubuntu1~xenialoverlay1~4+fix1 is installed.                                          - libqt5core5a, but 5.6.1+dfsg-3ubuntu1~xenialoverlay1~4+fix1 is installed.
                                Depends: qtdeclarative-abi-5-5-0 which is a virtual package, provided by:
                                          - libqt5qml5, but 5.6.1-4ubuntu1~xenialoverlay1~4 is installed.
 libubuntutoolkit5 : Depends: qtbase-abi-5-5-1 which is a virtual package, provided by:
                               - libqt5core5a, but 5.6.1+dfsg-3ubuntu1~xenialoverlay1~4+fix1 is installed.                               - libqt5core5a, but 5.6.1+dfsg-3ubuntu1~xenialoverlay1~4+fix1 is installed.
 aptdaemon : Breaks: python3-aptdaemon.pkcompat but 1.1.1+bzr982-0ubuntu14 is to be installed.
 webbrowser-app : Depends: qtbase-abi-5-5-1 which is a virtual package, provided by:
                            - libqt5core5a, but 5.6.1+dfsg-3ubuntu1~xenialoverlay1~4+fix1 is installed.                            - libqt5core5a, but 5.6.1+dfsg-3ubuntu1~xenialoverlay1~4+fix1 is installed.
                  Depends: qtdeclarative-abi-5-5-0 which is a virtual package, provided by:
                            - libqt5qml5, but 5.6.1-4ubuntu1~xenialoverlay1~4 is installed.
 libubuntugestures5 : Depends: qtdeclarative-abi-5-5-0 which is a virtual package, provided by:
                                - libqt5qml5, but 5.6.1-4ubuntu1~xenialoverlay1~4 is installed.
Internal error: found 2 (choice -> promotion) mappings for a single choice.
Internal error: found 2 (choice -> promotion) mappings for a single choice.
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

      Keep the following packages at their current version:    
1)      checkbox-converged [Not Installed]                     
2)      checkbox-gui [Not Installed]                           
3)      liboxideqt-qmlplugin [Not Installed]                   
4)      liboxideqtcore0 [Not Installed]                        
5)      liboxideqtquick0 [Not Installed]                       
6)      libqt5organizer5 [Not Installed]                       
7)      libubuntugestures5 [Not Installed]                     
8)      libubuntutoolkit5 [Not Installed]                      
9)      libunity-webapps0 [Not Installed]                      
10)     python3-aptdaemon.pkcompat [Not Installed]             
11)     qml-module-ubuntu-components [Not Installed]           
12)     qml-module-ubuntu-layouts [Not Installed]              
13)     qml-module-ubuntu-test [Not Installed]                 
14)     qml-module-ubuntu-web [Not Installed]                  
15)     qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-ui-toolkit-plugin [Not Installed]
16)     ubuntu-desktop [Not Installed]                         
17)     unity-webapps-common [Not Installed]                   
18)     unity-webapps-qml [Not Installed]                      
19)     unity-webapps-service [Not Installed]                  
20)     webapp-container [Not Installed]                       
21)     webbrowser-app [Not Installed]                         



Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] n
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

      Install the following packages:                                                                                    
1)      liboxideqtcore0 [1.13.6-0ubuntu1 (xenial)]                                                                       

      Keep the following packages at their current version:                                                              
2)      checkbox-converged [Not Installed]                                                                               
3)      checkbox-gui [Not Installed]                                                                                     
4)      liboxideqt-qmlplugin [Not Installed]                                                                             
5)      liboxideqtquick0 [Not Installed]                                                                                 
6)      libqt5organizer5 [Not Installed]                                                                                 
7)      libubuntugestures5 [Not Installed]                                                                               
8)      libubuntutoolkit5 [Not Installed]                                                                                
9)      libunity-webapps0 [Not Installed]                                                                                
10)     python3-aptdaemon.pkcompat [Not Installed]                                                                       
11)     qml-module-ubuntu-components [Not Installed]                                                                     
12)     qml-module-ubuntu-layouts [Not Installed]                                                                        
13)     qml-module-ubuntu-test [Not Installed]                                                                           
14)     qml-module-ubuntu-web [Not Installed]                                                                            
15)     qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-ui-toolkit-plugin [Not Installed]                                                          
16)     ubuntu-desktop [Not Installed]                                                                                   
17)     unity-webapps-common [Not Installed]                                                                             
18)     unity-webapps-qml [Not Installed]                                                                                
19)     unity-webapps-service [Not Installed]                                                                            
20)     webapp-container [Not Installed]                                                                                 
21)     webbrowser-app [Not Installed]                                                                                   

      Downgrade the following packages:                                                                                  
22)     oxideqt-codecs-extra [1.19.4-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 (now, xenial-security, xenial-updates) -> 1.13.6-0ubuntu1 (xenial)]



Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] n
```

I think this could possibly be related to the launchpad question here https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/433070 which inevitably points out some conflict between qtbase-abi-5-5-1 and qtbase-abi-5-6-1 but I don't have the expertise to conclusively determine that. Given my output, it ceertainly seems like something is up with my Qt libraries (which I don't mess with).

For completeness:

```
$ lsb_release -crid
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

Comment: It would help analysis tremendously if you would edit your question and add the output from `sudo aptitude install ubuntu-desktop`.

Comment: @OrganicMarble updated as requested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case another Ubuntu internet wanderer stumbles across a similar issue to the above and is wondering if a fresh installation is necessary, then the answer for my case was yes. If you have a suitable backup then this really isn't too onerous. Just make sure you don't pollute your new installation with anything other than 'pure data'. I have started using VMs in which I install third party software in order to 'sandbox' them and isolate them from my host OS which I am attempting to keep as vanilla as possible so that upgrades go smoothly in the future.

See https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2350343 for some more in depth answers to my questions over at UbuntuForums.